# Differnt raid setups in one array

Tags: raid, truenas

I am thinkig of dedicating PC for home NAS.
Considering Rockstor or XigmaNAS.
I have 2 identical disks and raid chip onboard.
Here is question: is it posible to have one partition in mirroring mode (eg raid1) for personal stuff. And rest of space in regullar use (raid0)?
I know raid shuould not be considered as backup strategy but it would give me a piece of mind.

Comment: Using a disk in multiple raid configurations will kill any performance gains you are going to get by using RAID 0. Just create one large drive in RAID 1 and partition it.

Answer (score 0):

You generally should be able tp create several different arrays on the same disks. For example, on a computer which has 2x WD 10TB Golds you can make with 1/4 of the space a RAID 1 for redundancy and the rest of 3/4 RAID 0 for performance.

This used to work even on ICH10 controller series.
It really depends on the controller, so yours could support that too.